# Is it possible to display an OpenLayers map upside-down?

Tags: openlayers-2

This is more fun than a serious question, but I'd like to know if it's possible to display an OpenLayers map upside-down as per the uncommon, but [interesting upside-down maps](http://flourish.org/upsidedownmap/).

I guess it's mostly a matter of finding a source of the tiles and turning them 180 degrees, but I figure it's something someone has already thought through.  I'm not the only one who's interested in the stories that are (or are not) being told through maps.

Comment: Like it. You could test it with vector data and a custom map projection (WGS84 rotated 180) maybe?

Comment: How would you rotate a the tiles 180 degrees?

Comment: rotating the tiles won't give you what you're looking for. You'll have to rotate the original image the tiles where generated from then regenerate the tiles from that rotated image.

Answer (score 3):

If you choose to store your data in PosGIS 2.0 you could make use of the new [ST_FlipCoordinates](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_FlipCoordinates.html)  function.

Example code snippet for a linestring:

```
SELECT ST_ASText( ST_FlipCoordinates(geom) ) as geom_flipped 
FROM ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(762091  2920414,762588 2920692,762676 2920779)‘,26986)  As geom;


--- geom_flipped -- 
LINESTRING(2920414 762091,2920692 762588,2920779  762676)
```

Thinking in polygons it would look somehow like that:

[image]

(Code and image source: [PostGIS 2.0 the new stuff](http://www.postgis.us/downloads/FOSS4G2011PostGIS20NewStuff.pdf) presentation by Regina Obe and Leo Hsu)

Comment: That's neat, but is the step beyond what I was looking for.  I'm curious about the tiles to start with.